# What's the difference between 好む and 好き

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between [好]{この}む and [好]{す}き?

Comment: Difference in grammatical usage? Or difference in meaning?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, they belong to different word classes. 好き is a na-adjective, and 好む is a transitive verb.

- リンゴ**が**好き**です**。 I like apples.
- リンゴ**を**好み**ます**。 I like apples.

Semantically, they both mean "to like [something]", but 好き is **much** more common in Japanese, and you should be using it most of the time.

In English, there is both a verb version ("I like apples") and an adjective version ("I am fond of apples") to describe this idea, but people usually use the former version. In Japanese, this is different, and we normally use the na-adjective version. In Japanese, 好む is a word that is only *sometimes* used in stiff sentences.

Answer (score 2):

好む/好み = Prefer, or for formal / objective usage

好き = Like, casual and subjective usage

It's safer to use 好む when talking about someone else's tastes. If you need to use like in a business setting, it would be appropriate to use 好み.

Comment: that's useful to me! thank you:)